# Including navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a class Conversation which has a navigation property `List<Message> Messages`, and every Message has a navigation property `User Owner`, and now when I do something like

```
        foreach (var item in conversation.Messages.ToList())
        {
            //Do something with item.Owner.Name
        }
```

it hits the database for every item.Owner...

How can I eager load the owner of message also when fetching messages in `conversation.Messages.ToList()`?

Comment: Are the navigation properties marked as virtual? I think that causes lazy loading

Comment: An example of eager loading: `var messages = context.Conversations.Include("Messages").ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eager load several nested levels you have two options:

- Using [`DbQuery<TResult>.Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696785(v=vs.113).aspx) method. In your case it would be:

  ```
  var query= context.Conversations.Include("Messages.Owner");
  ```

  This method receive as parameter the path of related objects you want to include in your query result.
- Using [`QueryableExtensions.Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx) extension method. In your case it would be:

  ```
  var query= context.Conversations.Include(c=>c.Messages.Select(m=>m.Owner));
  ```

  In this case you need to pass as parameter a lambda expression which represent the path to include. IMHO this is the better option due to is strongly typed and in case you change the name of one of the properties you are including, you're going to have a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

In your repository you get your conversation like this :

```
return (from c in context.Conversation
       where <your where clause>
       select c).Include(x => x.Messages.Select(m => m.Owner)).FirstOrDefault();
```